# Can't install package for Node.js on Windows

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, node.js

I try to install [iconv](https://npmjs.org/package/iconv) package for Node.js on Windows 8.1.

First, I installed Visual C + + 2005 Express Edition, because the console returns an error:
[image]

But now, the console returns a different error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are all the libraries from the first screen installed? 
The second screenshot says that compilers can not find the project file on the path d:\schedule\node_modules\iconv\build\iconv.vcproj

Try open project in the VS and compile it from her, and then try again to install iconv npm

Comment: Русский язык на этом сайте неуместен. Такие ответы модераторы или удаляют, или -- при приступах доброты -- переводят в Google Translate. Второе сейчас произойдёт с этим ответом, правка в очереди на подтверждение.